# Expo iOS app crashing when install from test-flight

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, testflight

I am working on an application which works really fine when I run it from `expo-client`, but whenever I upload it on App store and download it from `testflight`, it crashes after showing `splash-screen`.

Here is my `App.json`

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "AppName",
    "description": "Something",
    "slug": "AppName-app",
    "scheme": "appName",
    "privacy": "public",
    "platforms": ["ios", "android", "web"],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": ".images/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": ".images/splash-Screen.jpg",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    }
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.myapp.myappru",
      "buildNumber": "11",
      "googleServicesFile": "",
      "config": {
        "googleMapsApiKey": "KEY"
      },
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "something"
        "NSCalendarsUsageDescription": "something",
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "something",
        "NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription": "something",
        "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "something",
        "UIBackgroundModes": "something"
      }
    }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`expo-version` : 39.0.5

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve this?